# Installed Version of Tensorflow different from what I see on Jupyter

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I recently installed an upgraded version of TensorFlow through the terminal by executing the command: "pip install --upgrade tensorFlow --user".

However, I see in my terminal: "Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (2.9.1)" , but when I check the version of tensorflow in my Jupyter, I get that the tensorflow version 2.4.0.

Any suggestions on how to get the updated version of Tensorflow in Jupyter?

Edit: I also have Python 3.8.7

[Jupyter Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5nYe.png)  

[Terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObTOZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You might see the different versions in both interfaces because **TensorFlow** is getting installed at a different place.

If you want  to install an upgraded TensorFlow version on your current working jupyter notebook, then:

1. You may need to open the `anaconda command prompt` in the same environment where you are using jupyter notebook and install the tensorflow using same code and check the TensorFlow version.

OR

2. You can also install it by running the same code in the same `jupyter notebook` cell.

> !pip install --upgrade
> tensorFlow --user